# Unable to locate required Cef/CefSharp dependencies

Tags: c#, 64-bit, console-application, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I have a C# console application that is deployed on client machines. While deploying in client machine I get System.TypeInitializationException.

In debug.log, I get the following errors:

```
Unable to locate required Cef/CefSharp dependencies:
Missing:CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe
Missing:CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.dll
Missing:CefSharp.Core.dll
Missing:CefSharp.dll
Missing:icudtl.dat
Missing:libcef.dll
Executing Assembly Path:C:\myapp
```

The problem is that all files are present in the C:\myapp directory (as specified here). Therefore, I'm not sure why these files aren't being loaded up. Also msvcp120.dll, msvcr120.dll, vccorlib120.dll included in c:\myapp directory

Comment: You can disable dependency checking, it's a parameter of Cef.Initialize

Comment: @amaitland The issue disappeared after reverting my code to simulate it again, so it was probably environment related.

Answer (score 9):

As many people, I followed the steps in the official [Quick Start article](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/173/how-to-use-cefsharp-chromium-embedded-framework-csharp-in-a-winforms-application) to setup the "Any CPU" configuration and I had the same problem with missing dependencies when `performDependencyCheck` was on.

This is because the article is actually incomplete!

For the "Any CPU" configuration to work, you need to follow all the steps in [Feature Request - Add AnyCPU Support #1714](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1714) (especially the last one!):

> - Add `<probing privatePath="x86"/`> to your `app.config` as outlined in    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4191fzwb.aspx
> - Set `Prefer 32bit` in your project properties see       http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2012/04/04/what-anycpu-really-means-as-of-net-45-and-visual-studio-11/
>     for some background
> - **Set `settings.BrowserSubprocessPath = @"x86\CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe";` when calling
>     `Cef.Initialize`**
>
> example below:
>
> ```
> [STAThread]
> public static void Main()
> {
>   var settings = new CefSettings();
>   settings.BrowserSubprocessPath = @"x86\CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe";
>
>   Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: false, browserProcessHandler: null);
>
>   var browser = new BrowserForm();
>   Application.Run(browser);
> }
> ```

Note: when using this code, I would still advise you to use `performDependencyCheck: true` since it will now report only genuine errors.

Comment: I would left performDependencyCheck in true

Comment: Yes you're right, performDependencyCheck should be left "true". I just quoted the example from the ticket. I'll add a not to my answer though. Thanks

Comment: settings.browserSubprocessPath can no longer be relative. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3112

Instead, use this:

settings.BrowserSubprocessPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("x86\\CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe");

Answer (score 3):

I meet the same problem today.

My CEFSharp program works fine when only opening my program, but it's failed when open the associating files.

When I double click to open an associating format file (eg: JPG format file), the application startup fails because of "Unable to locate required Cef/CefSharp dependencies" error.

I tried to set "performDependencyCheck: false", it works when right clicking to choose the My program to open the file. But when double click the jpeg file, the error still stay.

Then I tried to set the current directory to execute file path, it looks works, I think this issue rootcause sometimes is related with the current working folder not right.

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            string exeDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            if (exeDir != null)
            {
                Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(exeDir);
            }

            if (!Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: false, browserProcessHandler: browserProcessHandler))
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to Initialize Cef");
            }
```

Comment: This worked for me.  I was launching my CefSharp app from a browser using a custom URI Scheme, and the current directory was being set to the browser's directory (e.g., `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\[Version]\`).  Setting the current directory to the CefSharp application's location resolved the dependency check issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. first I saw that the Cef.Initialize()  function just don't work, so I enabled the performDependencyCheck option  like this:

```
Cef.Initialize(BrowserSettings, performDependencyCheck: true, browserProcessHandler: null);
```

(According to this example https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/master/CefSharp.MinimalExample.OffScreen/Program.cs)

and I saw **I am** missing some files.

Afterwards, the error kept showing up, even though I don't miss anything. so i disabled the performDependencyCheck option and it worked.(like this:

```
Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: false, browserProcessHandler: null);
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: The 55.0.0 packages have gitlink support so you can easily debug the source on your dev machine. https://github.com/GitTools/GitLink#gitlink

Comment: I got tempted to disable the performDependencyCheck too, but then I realised that I could not execute JavaScript in the main frame. So I would discourage  from doing so. See my answer instead.